# customer email field 1st step one page check out

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I'd like to capture customers email address on the 1st step of the one  page checkout.

They'd have the option to login, or continue as a guest by supplying their email address. this should also remove the required email from billing address entry.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using magento default checkout or any extension

Comment: Using magento default onepage